# mifare classic 1k - Android - Tranceive failed on reading block

Tags: android, nfc, mifare

I am trying to read blocks with mifare classic card 1k and android nfc (on galaxy nexus).

```
private final int mMaxSize = 64;

mClassic.connect();

boolean success = mClassic.authenticateSectorWithKeyA(1, MifareClassic.KEY_DEFAULT );
final ByteArrayBuffer b = new ByteArrayBuffer(mMaxSize);

if (success)
{   
    b.append(mClassic.readBlock(0), 0, 16);
    b.append(mClassic.readBlock(1), 0, 16);
    b.append(mClassic.readBlock(2), 0, 16);
    b.append(mClassic.readBlock(3), 0, 16);
}
```

If I want to read sector 0, that's all ok.
But if I want to read a different sector (for example sector 1), success has true value, but when the app go to `readBlock()`, an `IOException` is triggered and I have returned tranceiver failed.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: did you try the following link   http://mifareclassicdetectiononandroid.blogspot.in/

Answer (score 0):

In your code example you're authenticating for **sector 1** but then try to read blocks from **sector 0**. Remember sector and block numbers are zero-based. You may also be interested in [blockToSector(int block)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/MifareClassic.html#blockToSector%28int%29).

Answer (score 0):

you should

```
b.append(mClassic.readBlock(4), 0, 16);
b.append(mClassic.readBlock(5), 0, 16);
b.append(mClassic.readBlock(6), 0, 16);
b.append(mClassic.readBlock(7), 0, 16);
```

Comment: Please add a reason as to why the code should be changed to 4-7